# Correct way to init object in cython function

Tags: python, cython

I'm using following cython code:

```py
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()


cdef class Seen:
    cdef bint sint_

    def __cinit__(self):
        print('INIT seen object')
        self.sint_ = 0

    cdef saw_int(self, object val):
        self.sint_ = 1


def test(object val):
    test_type(val)


def test_type(object val, Seen seen=Seen()):
    print ('BEFORE:', seen.sint_)
    val = int(val)
    seen.saw_int(val)
    print ('AFTER:', seen.sint_)
```

Build it and call functions like so:

```py
import test
import numpy as np

test.test(-1)
print('')
test.test(np.iinfo(np.uint64).max)
```

The output which produces questions:

```
INIT seen object
BEFORE: False
AFTER: True

BEFORE: True
AFTER: True
```

---

---

As output states - `seen` object is not instantiated in second `test.test` call. But at the same time if change `test_type` declaration like so:

```py
cdef test_type(object val):
    cdef  Seen seen=Seen()
    ...
```

Init happens on each call.

So 2 questions:

1. Why 2 realizations of `test_type` is different? As far as I remember from cython docs these two is interchangable.
2. How should I pass `seen` object to the `test_type` with the default as init new one? If (..., Seen seen=Seen()) not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of a function is evaluated *once*, when the function is defined. If you want a new `Seen` instance each time you *call* `test_type`, do the following:

```
def test_type(object val, Seen seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = Seen()
    print ('BEFORE:', seen.sint_)
    val = int(val)
    seen.saw_int(val)
    print ('AFTER:', seen.sint_)
```

---

Caveat: I'm not very familiar with cython, so there might be a subtlety that I am missing. But this would be the issue in ordinary Python code, and I suspect the same issue applies here.

Comment: I've also ported my example to simple python - the problem persists. So it's not the cython problem at all rather my misunderstanding of instantiating default values in function calls. Thanks for clarify it.